# SMTP email not sent because SMTP host does not accept my email address

Tags: php, smtp, html-email

So i currently doing a system to trigger email once the registration is submitted and pending for approval. I used github stmp email for send emails.

During testing, i am using outlook as my smtp host.

**My current code**

```
$mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'abc@outlook.com';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '****';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         //Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    //TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('abc@outlook.com', 'name');
    $mail->addAddress('recipient@gmail.com');
```

However, now i would like to use my company's email instead of an outlook email as the sender email. My company email is as follow abc@kfc.com (example) , what SMTP host should i use to enable this feature ?

Comment: You would need to use your company's SMTP server. Otherwise any emails you generate using your company address would look like forgeries (which would be true)

Comment: @ADyson Alright, ill ask for it. If they do have a SMTP host, does it mean there will be their own port too ?

Comment: Well all services have to run on a port, yes. 25 is the default port for SMTP but your company may have configured it differently, especially if they require SSL or TLS encryption. You need to check the connection requirements when you ask for details of the server.

Comment: @ADyson i just need to change those settings and it should run right ?

Comment: In theory, yes. Like I said, check what the requirements are when you get details about the server.

Comment: @ADyson Alright, thank you so much.